# Identify DMA memory in /proc/mtrr and /proc/iomem?

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, dma

I wonder if there is a way to identify memory used for DMA mapping in some proc files, such as `mtrr` and `iomem`, or via `lspic -vv`.

In my `/proc/mtrr`, there is only one `uncachable` region, and it seems to be pointing at the 'PCI hole' at 3.5-4GB, almost.

```
base=0x0e0000000 ( 3584MB), size=  512MB, count=1: uncachable
```

By cross verifying with `/proc/iomem`, of this 512MB region, only the last 21 MB before 4GB is NOT consumed by PCI Bus, and that 21MB sliver is occupied by things like `pnp/IOAPIC/Reserved`.

So my questions are:

1. What is the signature of DMA region in `/proc/mtrr` and `/proc/iomem`
2. Are there other places, such as other proc files and commands that I can use to see DMA region?
3. It seems by adding rows to `/proc/mtrr`, a privileged user can change caching mechanism of any memory, at runtime. So besides the fact that DMA has to be lower 32bit(assuming without DAC), are there other special requirement for DMA memory allocation? If there are no further requirment, then maybe the only hint I can use to identify DMA memory would be `/proc/mtrr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMA (Direct Memory Access) is just where a device accesses memory itself (without asking CPU to feed the data to the device). For a (simplified) example of DMA; imagine a random process does a `write()`, and this bubbles its way up (through VFS, through file system, through any RAID layer, etc) until it reaches some kind of disk controller driver; then the disk controller driver tells its disk controller "transfer N bytes from this physical address to that place on the disk and let me know when the transfer has been done". Most devices (disk controllers, network cards, video cards, sound cards, USB controllers, ...) use DMA in some way. Under load, all the devices in your computer may be doing thousands of transfers (via. DMA) per second, potentially scattered across all usable RAM.

As far as I know; there are no files in `/proc/` that would help (most likely because it changes too fast and too often to bother providing any, and there'd be very little reason for anyone to ever want to look at it).

The MTTRs are mostly irrelevant - they only control the CPU's caches and have no effect on DMA requests from devices.

The `/proc/iomem` is also irrelevant. It only shows which areas devices are using for their own registers and has nothing to do with RAM (and therefore has nothing to do with DMA).

Note 1: DMA doesn't have to be in the lower 32-bit (e.g. most PCI devices have supported 64-bit DMA/bus mastering for a decade or more); and for the rare devices that don't support 64-bit it's possible for Linux to use an IOMMU to remap their requests (so the device thinks it's using 32-bit addresses when it actually isn't).

Note 2: Once upon a time (a long time ago) there were "ISA DMA controller chips". Like the ISA bus itself; these were restricted to the first 16 MiB of the physical address space (and had other restrictions - e.g. not supporting transfers that cross a 64 KiB boundary). These chips haven't really had a reason to exist since floppy disk controllers became obsolete. You might have a `/proc/dma` describing these (but if you do it probably only says "cascade" to indicate how the chips connect, with no devices using them).

Comment: thanks. I was trying to figure out this - if DMA uses uncachable memory type, then which function guarantees DMA buffers to be uncached? Originally I thought that is only determined by MTRR, hence I went to /proc/mtrr file. /proc/iomem contains not only device memory mapped IO but also system memory, so it might contains some information as well. But later I found x86 uses PAT nowadays, so MTRR are largely not important. Still, I failed to find what code guarantees that DMA buffers are UC, for example, from dma_alloc_coherent().

Comment: @QnA: In general; there are no caches between devices and RAM, so no DMA accesses are cached (and all DMA accesses can be considered "uncached"). When a device issues a read or write, CPU/s see the request and write any modified data from their caches back to RAM first, so devices read from/write to the most up-to-date version. Note: This isn't always strictly true (some chips have an eDRAM cache between RAM and everything else; and some chips support a new "direct cache access" feature where special devices can inject data directly into CPU caches).

Comment: @QnA: Also note that (with PAT); it's possible for one CPU to have a page of RAM mapped as "write-back" while a different CPU has the same page of RAM mapped as "uncached"; so the same "CPU that is caching needs to write back any modified data in response to an access from something that isn't caching" behavior is needed for more than just accesses from devices.

Comment: Thanks. What I am curious about is the synchronization between RAM and CPU cache, not that there is another cache between device and RAM. It seems like you are saying there is some hardware guarantee. Using PCI on x86 as an example: 1. after device writes to RAM, who syncs the RAM content to CPU cache? Is it DRAM controller/PCI Root Complex/PCI Device/Anything else? 2. before device reads from RAM, who dumps CPU cache and write buffer to RAM?

Comment: @QnA: Erm. Nothing needs to sync RAM and cache after it's too late, because its synced before it's too late (before the device does its read or write). E.g. if a PCI devices does a write to RAM, then CPUs are told to write modified data back to RAM, then the PCI device's write happens to the correct version of the data (and not a stale version of data in RAM); and then if CPU wants the data again afterwards it has to fetch from RAM back into cache.

Comment: hmm. feels like we are talking across each other... I think I get your point that even for a DMA_FROM_DEVICE transaction, CPU still needs to flush cache/write buffer before the transaction, so that it doesn't override the RAM data written by device. Sounds like there are cheaper ways to do this though, CPU can simply mark the cache/write buffer as 'invalid', so that they won't override RAM later. But anyways, my question is similar to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140118/2762678, i.e., the synchronization between RAM and cache, before/after DMA.

Comment: For example, if the DMA buffer given to device to read/write is marked as UC mem type, then it will be a non-issue, and my understanding is that this can only be done by MTRR or PAT. OR, maybe PCI directly talks to cache somehow and magically all DMA touched memory is effectively UC, without MTRR or PAT?

Comment: @QnA: There'd be a bunch of tricks/optimizations - e.g. if device is writing whole cache line CPU could invalidate cache line (even if cache line was modified); if device is reading and CPU has the cache line in "shared" state then CPU knows copy in RAM is most recent version and could do nothing, For the "CPU has a modified cache line and device is writing to part of it or reading" case there's no alternatives (CPU has to write the data back to RAM before device does its access).

Comment: @QnA: Changing MTRRs is extremely expensive (need to stop all CPUs, disable all caches and write back and invalidate all caches in all CPUs, then modify MTRRs, then turn caches back on) - you definitely don't want to do that every time any program does any (disk, network, sound, video, ...) IO. PAT is mostly unimportant for coherency (CPU must assume that a page mapped as "uncached" at one virtual address may be mapped as "write back" or something else at a different virtual address, so CPU still needs to do the cache coherency stuff).

Comment: @QnA: Mostly, cache coherency is a set of states ("MESI"/"MOESI"/whatever), plus a bunch of messages between agents (things like "I'm going to modify that shared cache line so all you other agents that have it in shared state need to change it to invalid state", etc). These messages would also be use to ensure that when a device accesses (potentially) cached data it behaves correctly (e.g. IO hub receiving a write from a device and telling CPUs "Hey, if you have this cache line in modified state then you need to write it back to RAM", etc).

Comment: Thanks @Brendan, that's was helpful. I found an article which says that x86 (largely) enforces DMA cache consistency on hardware level - https://lwn.net/Articles/2265/, and that explains why I didn't see PAT manipulations in x86 dma_alloc_coherent() code, unlike ioremap() which does tweak PAT bits. On a related note, it seems that Linux kernel does not enforce PAT consistency across multiple PTEs pointing to the same physical page, wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @QnA: 80x86 CPUs are designed to work properly when PAT is used differently for different PTEs pointing to the same memory - they have 2 different types of "uncached" to make it work ("uncached by MTTRs so no coherency traffic is needed" and "uncached by PAT only, so coherency traffic is still needed")

Comment: ok, I am not sure I understand the 2 types, but I can settle for now.